# How javascript "this" handles multiple selector returns from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was making a menu today, and I stumbled on this curious case, with the following HTML:

```
<div id="list1">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2 - Here is a Submenu
            <ul>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then i used the following js:

```
$('#list1 li').click(function(){
   $('.list-item').removeClass('list-item');
   $(this).addClass('list-item');
});
```

When I do this the class would only be applied to the outer `<li>`, but I wanted it to be applied to both the parent and child `LI`s.

Now my question is, how can I handle this "returns" so I apply the classes to both the parent and child `LI`s?

How does js handle these type of selectors? Is the event really running twice and removing the last class that was set?

Comment: @amnotiam i was merely pointing out my thought process, i removed the point of confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `$('#list1 li')` can select both levels of `li` tags inside `#list` and apply a click handler to both.  In addition, you are allowing the click to propagate up so it may be seen by more than just the one you click on.

If you only want the outer level, then you should use direct child specifications like this. and that will isolate what click handler is actually installed:

```
$("#list > ul > li")
```

This will only get the top level `li` tags.  And, the whole code would look like this:

```
$('#list1 > ul > li').click(function(){
   $('.list-item').removeClass('list-item');
   $(this).addClass('list-item');
});
```

If you want to isolate the removeClass operation to just the other LI tags at the same level, not across the entire document, then you can use something like this:

```
$('#list1 > ul > li').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('list-item').siblings().removeClass('list-item');
});
```

Your comments have me a bit confused about this LI tags you want clickable.  If you actually want the lower level to be clickable and then apply the list-item class to both the one that was clicked and the parent LI, then you can do that like this:

```
$('#list1 > ul > li > ul > li').click(function() {
   $("#list1 .list-item").removeClass('list-item');
   $(this).parents("li").add(this).addClass('list-item');
   return(false);   // stop event propagation
});
```

Comment: to elaborate, your event is bubbling up, you can also stop bubbling, but using the direct child specifications is better.

Comment: sorry , that was quite unclear, i wanted to say that the given code would only work for the top level, but i wanted both levels to have the class , fixed this 
:)

Comment: @jonathan - now you've got me totally confused.  Which LI tags do you want to be clickable?  And when once is clicked on, which LI tags to you want to have the list-item class and which do you want it removed from?

Comment: @jfriend00 i wanted to have the clicked Li and it's parent Li with the class, so both would be styled as if they were selected on the menu.

Comment: @jonathan - OK, I think the last option in my answer does that.  It uses the `.parents('li')` method to find all `li` parents to mark them too and removes all former `.list-item` classes in the `#list1` object.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not jQuery applies a method to one element in a list of elements or all of them depends on the method.

`.click()` and `.addClass()` will both be applied to all jQuery objects in your selector.

In your case, a click handler is applied to all `li` elements in `#list`.  `$(this)` applies to the specific `li` that was clicked on.

**However**, you have nested `li` elements, which means that multiple click handlers fire when you click on an inner nested `li`, both the nested `li` and it's parent `li`.

To prevent this event propagation through the dom tree, put a stopPropagation() call in your click handler:

```
$('#list1 li').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();

   $('.list-item').removeClass('list-item');
   $(this).addClass('list-item');
});
```

You can also `return false` from your handler, which stops propagation and prevents default actions.  This is specific to jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the stopPropagation(), I've never used it before and it just saved me a huge headache.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding a "current" page style:

```
$('#list1 > ul > li').on('click',function(){
   $(this).addClass('list-item')    //adds class to clicked item
        .siblings()                 //find the others of the same level
        .removeClass('list-item');  //remove their styles
});
```